# Java String split() method returns unexpected length of string array

Tags: java, split

```
String source = "s5 g900 sued_p033178672__.____ ____.__4.5cm"; // __ __ is not a delimiter 

String deli = "__.__"; // this is my separator string to split target

String[] splittedString = source.split(deli, -1);

splittedString.length; // I expected 3 but was 4
```

what should I do to split target string properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.split()` takes a regular expression as its input. Therefore, `.` matches any characters, so `"__ __"` is treated as a delimiter as well.

To make it matches only `"__.__"`, you need to escape the special character `.`, i.e.,

```
String deli = "__\\.__";
```